# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 don t get it?

Tags: php, mysql

the text i get in the browser:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'username'= 'cAASDASD'' at line 1
```

maybe it is in this part?
otherwise i have no more 'WHERE'.

```
public function user_exists($username) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try {
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error syntax is for a query with a WHERE clause, so it's probably not the function you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error doesn't relate to the snippet of PHP code you're showing. Going by the error message, it looks like you're using something like:

```
$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = ?");
```

Here, the table and column are both using single quotes rather than back ticks. What you want is:

```
$query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
```

Answer (score 1):

in the *real* code you run there are `'single quotes'` are used around table name, not backticks as in one posted here

And you have no idea where this error occurred because of the [wrong way of using exceptions](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch). So, as soon as you remove that useless try-catch, as soon you will be informed of the exact place where error occurred